# Define default values for fields added with relationExtendManageWidget()

Tags: octobercms

I need to dynamically add fields to a relation manager widget. Hopefully, [October CMS allow that](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations#extend-relation-behavior) by using relationExtendManageWidget() method.

So, there is my code :

```
public function relationExtendManageWidget($widget, $field, $model) {
    $widget->tabs['fields']['_property'] = array(
        'label' => 'Property',
        'span' => 'auto',
        'type' => 'text',
        'tab' => 'Properties',
        'default' => 'test',
    );
}
```

My problem is that the default value "test" defined here only appears when I create a new relation. If I update existing one, the value is empty. I would like to know how to define value for my dynamic fields for **create and update** forms.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Its because in current records value [from db] for `_property` will be `empty` so field created by form `_proprty` will get value `blank` so it will show `bloank`

but for new records its new record so there is no db record to fill its value and it get default value `test`

and it seems fine to me it **must be the current behavior**

> but if you want to change `behavior` we can do something like this

```
public function relationExtendManageWidget($widget, $field, $model) {

    // you can use new array syntex [] in php 7.0
    $fieldConfiguration = [
        'label' => 'Property',
        'span' => 'auto',
        'type' => 'text',
        'tab' => 'Properties',
    ];

    // we check record is new or updating
    if($model->exists && $model->_property == '') {
        // we are updating record and seems _property field is ''/empty
        // so we fill it with 'test'
        $model->_property = 'test';
    }
    else {
        // record is new
        $fieldConfiguration['default'] = 'test';
    }

    $widget->tabs['fields']['_property'] = $fieldConfiguration;
}
```

> but now make sure you never able to save `empty value` for `_property` field as we decide to make it `test` when its empty. [**for existing records**]

if any doubts please comment and I am not sure you didn't post schema of you models if you post them it will be little easy to cast correct answer.